# Автоматическое монтирование samba дисков ubuntu

Tags: samba, wine, ubuntu

В windows есть удобная штука, можно подключить сетевой диск, и после перезагрузки он ни куда не денется, даже в случае когда диск недоступен. Конечная цель у меня - это монтирование такого диска в wine. А это в свою очередь необходимо для использования персонального поиска яндекс.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Сперва поставь пакет `smbfs`, затем добавь в `/etc/fstab что-то` типа

```
//192.168.100.100/dir /mnt/dir cifs -o     username=user,password=123,workgroup=group,uid=1000,gid=1000,rw 0 0
```

И будет счастьеА почему именно `wine`?Если диск виндовый, в параметры нужно добавить `iocharset=utf8,codepage=cp866`.

Comment: После "а почему" не очень понятно. Wine нужен для работы программы "персональный поиск яндекс".

Comment: пробовал, ни как не получается. а конкретно для начала решил в терминале поэкспериментировать.(при монтировании из nautilusa никаких паролей и т.д. не спрашивал)alexander@alexander-A17:~$ sudo mount //192.168.1.2/C /mnt/samba smbfs[sudo] password for alexander: Usage: mount -V                 : print version       mount -h                 : print this help...A device can be given by name, say /dev/hda1 or /dev/cdrom,or by label, using  -L label  or by uuid, using  -U uuid .Other options: [-nfFrsvw] [-o options] [-p passwdfd].For many more details, say  man 8 mount .

Comment: Я просто прочитал "монтирование в wine", понял это как монтирование средствами wine.Не mount, а mount.cifs после установки smbfsmount.cifs //10.10.10.10/sahre /mnt/share -o rw,username=user,password=password,domain=domain,iocharset=utf8,codepage=866,uid=1000,gid=1000Свои uid и gid можно посмотреть командой id. Их можно и не писать, просто может получиться, что не будет прав на запись.

Comment: mount.cifs //192.168.1.3/C /mnt/share -o rw,username=user,password=,domain=domain,iocharset=utf8ругается, говорит: Couldn't chdir to /mnt/share: No such file or directoryя подключаю папку "С", называю подключенную папку share (на "С" также ругается), имя пользователя на удалённой машине "user" пароля нет, что с доменом делать не понял (у меня ж вроде как локалка, или там по умолчанию настройка?), используем кодировку символов utf8правильно всё понял? По поводу логина пароля у меня сомнения они ведь не запрашиваются когда самба к папке подключается, там что то вроде гостевого входа.

Comment: /mnt/share создана?domain можно не указывать вообще

Comment: создал папку, теперь пишетmount.cifs: permission denied: no match for /mnt/share found in /etc/fstab

Comment: sudo надо сделать, видимо. Ну и если про fstab пишет, значит один параметр пропущен

Answer (score 2):

Возникал и у мну такой вопрос... [Тут нашел инструкцию.](http://www.lissyara.su/articles/freebsd/file_system/mount_smbfs/) От туда же:

> Всё оказалось гораздо проще - я вводилназвания серверов, домена, и имяпользователя маленькими буквами... Анадо было большими...

Не смотря на то, что инструкция для `FreeBSD`, работает и на Ubuntu (возможно - с минимальными правками, завтра, если не забуду, отпишу точнее...)Может поможет...

Comment: забыл (( точно забыл...

Answer (score 2):

Автомонтирование осуществляется средствами конфига /etc/fstab, пример:

```
//192.168.1.1/public /mnt/public cifs username=user,password=pass,noperm,dir_mode=0777,file_mode=0777,iocharset=utf8,_netdev 0 0
```

В современных дистрибутивах используется файловая система cifs, smbfs считается устаревшей. В некоторых системах требуется установка пакета cifs-utils, например, Mint.